# How do I find where an application is installed?

Tags: installation, 12.10, paths, installed-programs

I installed `wireshark` recently. I have no idea in which directory it was installed, but it's not in `/opt`.

How do I find where it's installed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you installed it from the repos:

```
$ dpkg -L wireshark wireshark-common 
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/wireshark
/usr/share
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/wireshark
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/wsicon32.xpm
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/wireshark.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/wireshark
/usr/share/doc/wireshark/copyright
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/wireshark.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/wireshark.svg
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/wireshark.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/wireshark/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/wireshark/README.Debian

/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/editcap
/usr/bin/text2pcap
/usr/bin/dumpcap
/usr/bin/rawshark
/usr/bin/mergecap
/usr/bin/capinfos
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common
/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/wireshark-common
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man4
/usr/share/man/man4/wireshark-filter.4.gz
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/mergecap.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/capinfos.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dumpcap.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/editcap.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/text2pcap.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rawshark.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Answer (score 15):

`which wireshark` will lead you to the executable. The output could ressemble this :

```
$ which wireshark
  /usr/bin/wireshark
```

Software never gets installed into `/opt` unless you yourself do that.

Comment: it only works in this particular case. what if I was to install "my super program", how would I find its path?

Comment: @AlanDert `which "my super program"` will work. As will locate `locate "my super program"`.

Comment: @AlanDert why would it not work? :) `which` checks the current environment so it will find it if you can execute it.

Comment: Some packages do install in `/opt`, though none in the `main` repositories do this. Examples: Google Chrome, Adobe Reader (Canonical partner repository), Spotify, etc. Please also note that it is even an requirement to install in `/opt` for MyApps (extras.ubuntu.com). http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/

Comment: This answer is mostly wrong. `which program-name` returns the path to the *executable*, which can be completely different from the install location of a program(e.g. there is `/usr/bin/inkscape` but the installation is in `/usr/share/inkscape`). They are identical iff the program is a single executable without any need for system-wide resources/extensions/configurations.

Comment: @Bakuriu all you do is repeat what is in the answer: as stated it will lead to the executable. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend going with @Oli's answer, if that works for you.  For applications that you (for whatever reason) didn't install with the

You can examine the unity launcher icon, it may be able to tell you:

The launcher file will usually be located in `/usr/share/applications/`, and named something like `my-application-launcher.desktop`. If you don't know exactly what the file is called, use `ls` to examine the directory. (For your specific one, it is called `wireshark.desktop`.)

Once you know which one it is, examine its contents (anything from `cat` to `gedit` will work, but if you use gedit make sure to do it as `gksu gksu gedit`, not `sudo gedit`).

The file will contain an entry with something like `Exec=command` or `Exec=/path/to/script.sh`. If it only has a command, you can use `which` or `locate` (like @Rinzwind said) to get the full path for it.  Another option is to use `whereis` to find the binary or source location.

The directory containing the launcher's target should be the installation directory for the program.  If the launcher points to a shell script, sometimes examining its contents can reveal additional locations, if needed.

Running `gksu nautilus` when you get there will give you a windowed file browser with root permissions, meaning you can use it to copy/delete/edit any file, since normally installations are protected and will prevent you from modifying files as a normal user.

If that doesn't work, another option is to use `find`, to find anything with the same name, or `grep`, to find files containing the name.

**However, you should only do this if you don't have any better alternatives.**  This can be a slow, tedious, mind-numbing process, especially since sometimes there is more than one location that stuff is installed to.  If you can, use some other method.

Answer (score 2):

if nothing of the above works try `locate`. To do a `locate`-search on up to date information run `updatedb` before.

for more information, consult `man locate` and `man updatedb`

Answer (score -1):

`locate` keyword is best choice to check the installation directory of the program, look at the initial lines in the result of `locate wireshark`, and it will tell you all you require.